# how to assign query to GridItem in SearchView?

Tags: android, search

I am trying to create a SearchView that searches for GridItems that each launch a specific second activity. However I cannot figure out the code that will help me with this. I have already set an onQueryTextChangeListener for the SearchView which should allow me to show results manually and whilst typing.  Here's what I want to happen:

When I type a specific query, let's say "car", I want to show the GridItem (which is just a clickable ImageView) of a car to the user. When I type "Camera", I want to show the user my GridItem with the image of a Camera on it.

I also want to display results to the user whilst typing, so when I have only typed "c" yet, I want to show the user both the "car" and "Camera" GridItems. I want to stay in the same activity, so I need some sort of way to delete all GridItems except for the ones with a camera or a car picture on it depending on what the user typed, I don't want to launch a search activity.

Now what makes this just a little harder is that I configured my BaseAdapter in a separate class, which means that I have to indirectly mention the GridItems in some way. Here's what I've done so far:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater =  getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)
            MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        if (query.equals(R.string.Coconut)){
        //here I need some code that will tell the system that I want to show the GridItem with a picture of a coconut on it
        }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
```

This is the separate class that initialises the Images in the GridView:

```
class SingleItem{
int image;
double nutritional_value;

    SingleItem(int image, double nutritional_value){
    this.image = image;
    this.nutritional_value = nutritional_value;



}
}
public class objectAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
ArrayList<SingleItem> list;
Context context;
Bundle myBundle;

objectAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    myBundle = new Bundle();
    double[][] nutritional_value = {
            {89, 22.8, 0.3, 1},
            {61, 1.5, 0.5, 1.1},
            {375, 6.8, 0.6, 1.2},
            {767, 0, 9.3, 0},
            {580, 9.1, 42, 36.5}



    };
    myBundle.putSerializable("array_array", nutritional_value);

    int[] image_id = {
            R.drawable.Bananas, R.drawable.Kiwis, R.drawable.oatmeals, R.drawable.coconuts,
            R.drawable.dark_chocolate
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < image_id.length; i++) {
        SingleItem tempSingleItem = new SingleItem(image_id[i], nutritional_value[i][i]);
        list.add(tempSingleItem);
    }
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
        holder= new ViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
        SingleItem temp = list.get(position);
        holder.myItem.setImageResource(temp.image);
    holder.myItem.setTag(temp);
    return row;
    }




@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView myItem;
            ViewHolder(View v){
myItem = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


            }
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}


}
```

Thanks in advance!

Vidal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some sort of a link between adapter items and string value (name or the index in string array). For example:

```
class SingleItem{
int image;
double nutritional_value;
String name;

    SingleItem(int image, double nutritional_value,String name){
    this.image = image;
    this.nutritional_value = nutritional_value;
    this.name = name;


}
}
```

If you want to make changes while user typing the query, you need to override

```
@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        adapter.filter(newText);
        return true;
    }
```

in ObjectAdapter class make changes. You need additional list of currently displaying items.

```
public class objectAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
ArrayList<SingleItem> list;
ArrayList<SingleItem> filteredItems;
Context context;
Bundle myBundle;

objectAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    myBundle = new Bundle();
    double[][] nutritional_value = {
            {89, 22.8, 0.3, 1},
            {61, 1.5, 0.5, 1.1},
            {375, 6.8, 0.6, 1.2},
            {767, 0, 9.3, 0},
            {580, 9.1, 42, 36.5}



    };
    myBundle.putSerializable("array_array", nutritional_value);

    int[] image_id = {
            R.drawable.Bananas, R.drawable.Kiwis, R.drawable.oatmeals, R.drawable.coconuts,
            R.drawable.dark_chocolate
    };

    int[] name_id = {R.string.Bananas, R.string.Kiwis, R.string.oatmeals, R.string.coconuts,
            R.string.dark_chocolate
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < image_id.length; i++) {
        SingleItem tempSingleItem = new SingleItem(image_id[i], nutritional_value[i][i],context.getResources().getString(name_id[i]));
        list.add(tempSingleItem);
    }

    filteredItems = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
    filteredItems.addAll(list);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
        holder= new ViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
        SingleItem temp = filteredItems.get(position);
        holder.myItem.setImageResource(temp.image);
    holder.myItem.setTag(temp);
    return row;
    }




@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView myItem;
    ViewHolder(View v){
       myItem = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    }
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filteredItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return filteredItems.size();
}


public void filter(String text) {
    filteredItems.clear(); 
    for(int i=0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
        SingleItem item = list.get(i);
        if (item.name.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()) {
           filteredItems.add(item);
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```